# Rate of Laptop Battery Charging

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, solar-cell, charging

Assuming I have a working solar panel system, all the things such as inverter, charge controller and battery are in place.

The state of battery will obviously change, some times it will fully charged and sometimes it wont be fully charged depending on my usage.

Now, If I try to charge my laptop with this solar-panel-battery, Will the charging time of laptop be dependent on charging state of solar-panel-battery, that is will there be a change in the way laptop is being charged if solar-panel-battery is 80% charged or if it is 100% charged?

Comment: It depends somewhat on the chemistry and capacity of each battery. For *reasonable* choices of both the answer would be that it won't make much difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually charging your laptop battery with the solar system battery. (At least, you shouldn't be.) Your laptop includes charging circuits to make sure your battery gets the voltages and currents to charge it properly. So long as those circuits are fed with voltage and current within their operating range, your laptop shouldn't care what the exact nature of the source is. AC line and switching converter, charged battery, discharged battery, all that's going to matter are voltage and current capacity.

Of course, there are a lot of details to "voltage and current capacity" that might bite you, this is a gross oversimplification, your mileage may vary, professional driver on a closed course, American Express cards not accepted.